# How to create a Xamarin.iOS app to activate kiosk mode (Lock the Device to a Single Application )?

Tags: c#, ios, .net, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I need to create a Xamarin.iOS app to activate kiosk mode (Lock the Device to a Single Application )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using MDM you can set up kiosk mode, to lock the device into a single app, via the iPhone Configuration Utility. You can refer to these cases:

[How can I programatically enable Guided Access (Kiosk mode) on an iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27488537/how-can-i-programatically-enable-guided-access-kiosk-mode-on-an-iphone)

or [Guided Access/Kiosk Mode of iPad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22500036/guided-access-kiosk-mode-of-ipad)

Otherwise you have to set up guided access on the device as this [article](https://www.howtogeek.com/252670/how-to-put-an-ipad-into-kiosk-mode-restricting-it-to-a-single-app/) described.

Comment: Thank you, but can it be done using Xamarin.iOS or only using the swift and Objective-C ?

Comment: I found it, Thank you very much