# How can I programmatically disable iphone home button in swift 4?

Tags: ios

I am going to develop an application for kids. That I needed is I have to lock the home button permanently for this particular application but I didn't get any solution for this.

Comment: `There is no way on this planet an app can programmatically disable the home button. The iPhone pretty much fails to work without it` for reference : [How to enable a 'kiosk mode' programmatically in ipad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15068318/how-to-enable-a-kiosk-mode-programmatically-in-ipad)

Comment: The user no need to open another application while using this application. The user of this application is mainly 4 - 9 years old children. This application is used for brain development and logical reasoning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For kids, there is a feature in the iPhone setting called "Guided Access" this setting lock the phone with one app. This could be helpful for you. You can mention [this](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202612) in your app.

You can use [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiaccessibility/1615186-requestguidedaccesssession) API to do programmatically. It was introduced in WWDC 2017. For more information how to use API and lock in a specific way. Please check [this](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/716/) video. For doing programmatically without any device management it has been explained at  15:40th minute.

Comment: can we enable "Guided Access" programmatically?

Comment: @AdarshKC Yes, you can but there is a limitation on that it has to be under Mobile Device Management. You can check the apple API doc for details.

Comment: When I search on the google it shows that there is a solution called Single app mode

https://www.howtogeek.com/252670/how-to-put-an-ipad-into-kiosk-mode-restricting-it-to-a-single-app/

Comment: @AdarshKC Yes using apple configurator but that's not an option for programmatically doing it. It's more like you wanna use one app on your shop or something.


Check this 
https://support.apple.com/en-hk/guide/apple-configurator-2/cadf1802aed/mac

It comes under device management settings.

Comment: But using app configurator it will erase all my data in ipad

Comment: yeah, don't do that. do you any particular issue with use of "requestGuidedAccessSession".

Comment: I have tried this but its only check if guided access is enabled or not 


UIAccessibility.requestGuidedAccessSession(enabled: true){
            success in
            if success{
                print("\(success)")
            }else{

Comment: @AdarshKC You need to check how to use that API. If you use directly without any setup. It's gonna return false. Which is just failed to enable. I have attached one video from WWDC it explains how to use that API. You will need a "com.apple.developer.edu-assessment-mode" entitle as well. Check on 15:40th Minute. And there is a whole lot of options available to choose how much control you want. 

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204775#AAC

Comment: I have tried many ways but it doesn't succeed the only solution for this is  "Guided Access".

Comment: @AdarshKC Did you got "com.apple.developer.edu-assessment-mode" entitlement from apple? As it's described in 15:40th minute of the video. You need to check with apple for that.

Comment: There is a sample code as well.
You can check ReadMe of that. That explains how to get the entitlement. 
https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/716/

Comment: I am checking on it